# How to find an empty cell and paste data in that one

Tags: google-apps-script

i need to know which function or code could i use in order to find the next empty cell in a sheet. Al i've been reading gives me the last empty row, but that doesn't work for me because i have formulas in other columns.
I'm copying a range from Sheet 1 and i need to find the next empty cell in Sheet 2 column B and paste that information i got from sheet 1 into that empty cell.
Do you know how to do it?

Thanks!

This is the function i have so far, being Consolidated the Sheet 2 in my example above.

```
function EmptyCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Consolidated"); 
  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  
  sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,2).activate();

    };
```

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55467286

Comment: Hi, it is not useful, doesn't solve my issue. Could we post my original question and check if anyone can help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.